# what do labor contractions actually feel like?

Tags: birth

I know this site is only about Parenting so hope this question is not too far off this site scope.

My wife is 37 weeks and 5 days into her pregnancy and till now she just used to have pains similar to menstrual cramps but since yesterday night her cramps are more regular about 2 hours apart, last for 20-30 mins and accompanied with a tightness of her stomach, which is new.

We did go in to the hospital yesterday and she and the baby checked out fine.

So i wanted to know, is she starting her contractions if not what do contractions actually feel like?

Comment: To anyone interested, the birth was successful, so successful that we had another child 3 years later. Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is what contractions feel like (although they get closer together, shorter, and stronger in labour).

These could be Braxton-Hicks contractions ("practice contractions") and just a sign that she needs to slow down and rest more and stay well-hydrated. You can also have days or weeks of what is called "prodromal labour" before the real thing happens. There's a good overview of Braxton-Hicks and prodromal labour here:
http://thebirthteacher.blogspot.co.uk/2008/12/prodromal-labor.html

Also, at 37w5d she's technically term anyway, so not a big problem if it does turn out to be the real thing.

Good luck :-)

Comment: Very useful to differentiate between labour contractions and "practice" (Braxton-Hicks) contractions.